# How do I give AWS Lambda JSON when using a CloudWatch Cron rule?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Lambda function in C#. When Im in Lambda under Actions -> Test Data I have this json (Simplified, for the sake of humanity):

```
    {
        "address": "http://website.com",
        "ID": "18",
        "pricingType": "INTERSTATE",
        "reportID": "1443",
        "XML": "<BASICSXMLSTUFF>"
    }
```

Which works when I click "Test". But I cannot figure out how to send this data to the function when I use a CloudWatch Cron Rule. I have attempted to put it in the "Constant (JSON text)" field in CloudWatch, but that doesnt seem to save and when the function runs I get this stack trace:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'resources', line 1, position 202.: JsonReaderException
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IDictionary dictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )
```

How can I pass the json to my lambda function using a CloudWatch Rule? Or am I just going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem, it looks like I was doing everything properly, but "Constant (JSON text)" must have a character limit. The XML I was passing into the function was extremely large so I changed it to download from a URL instead of supplying the XML that way and now everything is working perfectly.